# Visual Studio 2008 x64 /MP compiler switch

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, windows-7-x64

I have a problem with my newly installed VisualStudio 2008 SP1 on a Windows 7 SP1 x64 system.

I work on a project that's under Clearcase and the solution contains like 10 projects.

Each project has an additional compiler switch: "/MP", for optimization purpose. My colleagues build the projects with this switch (builds faster), but on x64 system gives some errors.

Is there a way to ignore this switch without checking out every project and delete this switch from the compiler options of each project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** I hadn't looked at the *particular option* you mentioned. It turns out it relates to parallel building and I think the suggestions by Hans make more sense in that case.

---

The best you could do is create build configurations for the 64bit builds so you can have separate sets of compile/link options.

On the short term, and for a proof-of-concept, I'd simply

- copy the entire worktree,
- make all files/folders writable on the copy
- delete any performance integration (so you can do whatever you want from VS, the usual way is to delete files *scc)
- open the solution(s) - you will be prompted about removing the source control bindings or working 'offline' temporarily; choose whatever you want, it is only a proof of concept
- edit the options (<kbd>Ctr-Alt-L</kbd>, select all projects, 'Properties', select 'All Configurations' to do this in bulk)
- compile

If all works, discuss whether you need 64bit support. If so, add the build configurations to the official repo version.

Comment: Well this would be the last solution, but I thought, that there is a master switch that can be given to the compiler globally, witch overrides the /MP switch.